Can a Time Machine APFS container be expanded without losing the backups in it?
I have an eight-terabyte drive partitioned as:
/dev/disk6 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.0 TB     disk6
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk6s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Seagate 3TB             3.0 TB     disk6s2
                    (free space)                         134.2 MB   -
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk7         5.0 TB     disk6s3

/dev/disk7 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +5.0 TB     disk7
                                 Physical Store disk6s3
   1:                APFS Volume Seagate 5TB             4.4 TB     disk7s2

5TB is a Time Machine backup; 3TB is empty.  How can I change it to give Time Machine the entire drive (merge the containers—including the free space—into one) without losing the backups already there?
This is on Sequoia 15.1.1 (24B91)

From poking around on the web, it seems that it can't be done because the backup partition is "after" the others.  Maybe I can duplicate the backups into the 3TB and then do it, erasing the original backups.  (No: backups already more than 3TB.)

I hate to say it but your only option may be to copy the TM backup to a separate hard drive, then reformat the current TM backup drive and merge the partitions, then copy it back over.  Tedious and annoying but should work.

@mweiss, I think you are correct.  Maybe not tedious, but it could take many hours to do the copy.  And, unfortunately, the backups are bigger than the second biggest drive I've got (Internal 4TB SSD with 2TB free).  I think I'll just leave it as is.

And also remember that it is only the very first backup that is a full one, all after the very first are only delta backups - which Time Machine have an internal “register” over

Actually, every backup is complete.  Hard links are used to prevent duplication of unchanged files.  Moreover, the file system is APFS, which internally uses a similar system to save space by not duplicating identical blocks.
